# NewsFeed WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I activate Site Feed feature in Site Settings --> Manage site features. when I added web part it show this error :

> Technical Details SharePoint returned the following error: Invalid URI: The URI is empty. Contact your system administrator for help in resolving this problem.

any ideas , which URI is missing ?

Comment: check mysite is configured or not

Comment: I create Mysite collection , and i stille have this progleme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troubleshooting tips:

1. Verify my site web application is created.
2. Go to Manage Service application--> User Profile service-- >Set up My Site(under My site settings)-->  Update the my site Host location. Also keep below setting:
   Check  Enable activities in My Site newsfeeds.
3. Reset IIS.

   Also verify whether newsfeed webpart is working in the my site page